# Weird Date from jDateChooser

Tags: java, date, jdatechooser

I used **jDateChooser**, downloaded from *toedter.com*. I add it to my palette and drag and drop to swing application. When I select the date from it, it works perfectly. But I want that date like 2015-01-01. I change `dateFormatString` to `YYYY-MM-DD`, it gives weird date. The problem is with the month, the year shows correctly. For example, If I select `2015-01-01`, It shows `2015-31-01`.

So what will be the solution to my matter. can anyone help me ?

Comment: what are the "weird" outputs?

Comment: change `dateFormatString` to `yyyy-MM-dd`

Comment: when I select 2015-01-01, It shows 2015-31-01.. Then close the application and select the same date then it shows 2015-32-01

Comment: @Madushan Perera..yeh.. Now it's OK to yyyy-MM-dd format. Thanks buddy..

Comment: Can I get my yyyy-MM-dd to String

Comment: Edited to improve question.